# Return a default value if a dictionary key is not available

Tags: python, dictionary, key, nonetype

I need a way to get a dictionary value if its key exists, or simply return `None`, if it does not.

However, Python raises a `KeyError` exception if you search for a key that does not exist. I know that I can check for the key, but I am looking for something more explicit. Is there a way to just return `None` if the key does not exist?

---

<sub>**See also:** [Why dict.get(key) instead of dict[key]?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11041405)</sub>

Comment: Just use `.get(key)` instead of `[key]`

Comment: Accessing the key and catching the exception is perfectly okay in Python. It is even a well known and oft-used design pattern. If you return None instead, it becomes impossible to store None as a value, which may be relevant in some cases.

Comment: Sometimes you want to treat "None" entries in the dictionary and missing entries the same, in that case the accepted answer seems to do the job just fine.

Answer (score 1291, accepted):

You can use [`dict.get()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

```
value = d.get(key)
```

which will return `None` if `key is not in d`. You can also provide a different default value that will be returned instead of `None`:

```
value = d.get(key, "empty")
```

Comment: Note that the second variant with a default fallback will still return `None` if the key is explicitly mapped to `None` in the dict. If that's not what you want, you can use something like `d.get(key) or "empty"`.

Comment: @cib: Good point, but the solution has a similar problem - if the key is mapped to any "falsy" value (like `[]`, `""`, `False`, `0.0` or indeed `None`), then your solution would always return `0`. If you expect `None`s as values, you will have to do the `if key in d:` check explicitly.

Comment: @cib cheers for that, I couldn't work out what I was doing wrong here.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - can you please explain your answer? d.get(key) or "empty" in case of key being mapped to any 'falsy' values is "empty" if i am not mistaken.

Comment: @MiloMinderbinder: `"empty"` is returned if `key` is not a valid key in `d`. It has nothing to do with the value `key` is mapped to.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - d.get(key) or "empty" ... would that not return "empty" if key is present but the key is mapped to 0. (or any "falsy" value . like None,[]). example: a = {'a':0,'b':1}

a['a'] or "empty"

Comment: Ah, now I see what you meant. I didn't read your question carefully enough. I was looking at my answer (`d.get(key, "empty")`, which doesn't have that problem) instead of the `or` variant.

Comment: an example with the walrus would be cool ;)

Answer (score 72):

Wonder no more. It's built into the language.

```
    >>> help(dict)

    Help on class dict in module builtins:

    class dict(object)
     |  dict() -> new empty dictionary
     |  dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's
     |      (key, value) pairs
    ...
     |  
     |  get(...)
     |      D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.
     |  
    ...
```

Answer (score 35):

Use [`dict.get`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Returns the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

Answer (score 35):

You should use the `get()` method from the `dict` class

```
d = {}
r = d.get('missing_key', None)
```

This will result in `r == None`.  If the key isn't found in the dictionary, the get function returns the second argument.

Comment: You do not have to pass `None` explicitly. It is the default.

Answer (score 26):

I usually use a [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) for situations like this. You supply a factory method that takes no arguments and creates a value when it sees a new key. It's more useful when you want to return something like an empty list on new keys ([see the examples](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples)).

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(lambda: None)
print d['new_key']  # prints 'None'
```

Comment: The problem with the `defaultdict` is that it will keep growing each time a non-existing element is requested.

Comment: This can also be the desired behavior, like when you're trying to build a nested dict with a loop.

Answer (score 25):

If you want a more transparent solution, you can subclass `dict` to get this behavior:

```
class NoneDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return dict.get(self, key)

>>> foo = NoneDict([(1,"asdf"), (2,"qwerty")])
>>> foo[1]
'asdf'
>>> foo[2]
'qwerty'
>>> foo[3] is None
True
```

Comment: @marineau: As i mentioned in a comment to another answer, the problem with the `defaultdict` is that it will grow each time an element that is not yet in there is requested. This is not always desirable.

Comment: @BjörnPollex This is by far the elegant one, Any clue on how to extend this to support any depth? I mean making `foo['bar']['test']['sss']` to return `None` instead of exception, After one depth it start giving `TypeError` instead of `KeyError`

Comment: @itsneo. You could build the entire structure of `NoneDicts`. This would help in case the `KeyError` would happen in the innermost object. Otherwise the problem is, that once you return a `None` object you can't subscribe it anymore. One ugly hack would be to return another object that tests like `None`. Beware however that this could lead to horrible bugs.

Comment: @BjörnPollex Is it okay to change `return dict.get(self, key)` to `return super().get(key)`? Then if I decide to use OrderedDict instead of dict, for example, I don't have to worry about changing multiple lines of code.

Comment: @Wood Yes, that would actually be much nicer!

Comment: What if we want to return a default value other than None?

Comment: @sh37211 then adjust the call to `.get` within the class, **in exactly the same way that you would** if following the other answers and calling `.get` directly.

Comment: Arguably it would be better to implement this technique using `__missing__` rather than by overriding the `__getitem__` logic. That hook was explicitly provided for cases like this one.

Answer (score 13):

A one line solution would be:

```
item['key'] if 'key' in item else None
```

This is useful when trying to add dictionary values to a new list and want to provide a default:

eg.

```
row = [item['key'] if 'key' in item else 'default_value']
```

Comment: That's a very intriguing approach. Thanks for adding this answer. I'll definitely explore this for a use-case.

Answer (score 12):

As others have said above, you can use get().

But to check for a key, you can also do:

```
d = {}
if 'keyname' in d:

    # d['keyname'] exists
    pass

else:

    # d['keyname'] does not exist
    pass
```

Comment: I now see that you already know how to do this. I was going to delete my post, but I'll leave it for reference for others.

Comment: This approach usually requires the key to be looked-up twice when it's there, which is probably the reason for the `get` method.

Answer (score 10):

You could use a `dict` object's `get()` method, as others have already suggested. Alternatively, depending on exactly what you're doing, you might be able use a `try/except` suite like this:

```
try:
   <to do something with d[key]>
except KeyError:
   <deal with it not being there>
```

Which is considered to be a very "Pythonic" approach to handling the case.

Comment: I would argument that this would violate the "explicit instead of implicit" principle, and make the intent unclear. Not to mention the fragility and verbosity.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK: I could not disagree more, it's very explicit.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree that this is actually a very explicit approach. While it does make for more lines of code (get() is effectively a single line), it IS very readable.

Answer (score 4):

For those using the `dict.get` technique for nested dictionaries, instead of explicitly checking for every level of the dictionary, or extending the `dict` class, you can set the default return value to an empty dictionary except for the out-most level. Here's an example:

```
my_dict = {'level_1': {
             'level_2': {
                  'level_3': 'more_data'
                  }
              }
           }
result = my_dict.get('level_1', {}).get('level_2', {}).get('level_3')
# result -> 'more_data'
none_result = my_dict.get('level_1', {}).get('what_level', {}).get('level_3')
# none_result -> None
```

**WARNING:** Please note that this technique only works if the expected key's value is a dictionary. If the key `what_level` did exist in the dictionary but its value was a string or integer etc., then it would've raised an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 0):

I was thrown aback by what was possible in python2 vs python3. I will answer it based on what I ended up doing for python3. My objective was simple: check if a json response in dictionary format gave an error or not. My dictionary is called "token" and my key that I am looking for is "error". I am looking for key "error" and if it was not there setting it to value of None, then checking is the value is None, if so proceed with my code. An else statement would handle if I do have the key "error".

```
if ((token.get('error', None)) is None):
    do something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use try-except block

```
try:
    value = dict['keyname']

except IndexError:
    value = None
```

Answer (score 0):

1. d1={"One":1,"Two":2,"Three":3}
2. d1.get("Four")

If you will run this code there will be no 'Keyerror' which means you can use 'dict.get()' to avoid error and execute your code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a more complex requirement that equates to a cache, this class might come in handy:

```
class Cache(dict):
    """ Provide a dictionary based cache

        Pass a function to the constructor that accepts a key and returns
        a value.  This function will be called exactly once for any key
        required of the cache.
    """

    def __init__(self, fn):
        super()
        self._fn = fn

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return super().__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            value = self[key] = self._fn(key)
            return value
```

The constructor takes a function that is called with the key and should return the value for the dictionary.  This value is then stored and retrieved from the dictionary next time.  Use it like this...

```
def get_from_database(name):
    # Do expensive thing to retrieve the value from somewhere
    return value

answer = Cache(get_from_database)
x = answer(42)   # Gets the value from the database
x = answer(42)   # Gets the value directly from the dictionary
```

Answer (score -5):

If you can do it with `False`, then, there's also the [hasattr](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) built-in funtion:

```
e=dict()
hasattr(e, 'message'):
>>> False
```

Comment: please don't do that consider most upvoted