# How to check if all values in a dictionary exist in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I have a dictionary of user preferences that I'd like to check and see if ALL of the dictionary values exist in a list.

For example, I have a dictionary like:

```
dct = { 'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value2'}
```

And I have a list like so:

```
lst = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3', 'list4']
```

I'm trying to check if all of the values in the dictionary exist in the list.

How do I do this?

EDIT to be more specific:

My dictionary is

```
userprefs = {'RON' : 'PHX'}
```

My list is

```
poss_matches = [['misc0', 'misc1', 'misc2', 'misc3', 'misc4', 'misc5', 'misc6', 'misc7', 'PHX-']]
```

However, if I use something like:

```
    for seq in poss_matches:
        for p in userprefs:
            if userprefs[p] in seq:
                matches.append(seq)
```

I get an empty list for matches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return None if Dictionary key is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130768/return-none-if-dictionary-key-is-not-available)

Comment: @cph_sto: they are not keywords, but names of built-ins, keywords are `lambda`, `return`, `def`, etc. and using them as objects names will end up in `SyntaxError`

Comment: Sorry, I just used those variable names for example, I'm not actually using the names of built-ins.

Comment: I'll edit the OP to be more specific!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this :

```
def checker():
    for value in dct.values():
        if value in lst:
            continue
        else:
            return False
    return True

dct = { 'key1' : 'list1', 'key2' : 'list1'}
lst = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3', 'list4']
print(checker())
```

By this you will be fetching values from dictionary in value variable and checking whether it's present in list.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

```
myDict = { 'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value2'}
values_myDict = myDict.values() # Outputs all the values of a dictionary in a list.
values_myDict
    ['value1', 'value2']

# Use set() - In case myList has all the values of the dictionary, we will get True, else False
myList = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3', 'list4', 'value1', 'value2']
bool_value = set(values_myDict) < set(myList)
bool_value
    True     # because both 'value1' & 'value2' are presnt.

myList = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3', 'list4', 'value1',]
bool_value = set(values_myDict) < set(myList)
bool_value
    False    # because 'value2' is not present.
```

**Method 2:** As suggested by *Jon Clements*. A more concise and succinct one.

```
myDict = { 'key1' : 'value1', 'key2' : 'value2'}
myList = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3', 'list4', 'value1', 'value2']
bool_value = set(myDict.values()).issubset(myList)
bool_value
    True

myList = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3', 'list4', 'value1']
bool_value = set(myDict.values()).issubset(myList)
bool_value 
    False
```

Comment: Many thanks Jon for your remarks. I made an additional update.

Answer (score 1):

You need `all()` with `for loop`

```
dct = { 'key1' : 'list1', 'key2' : 'list2','k3':'list3','k4':'list4'}
lst = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3', 'list4']

all(x in lst for x in dct.values())
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: I'm trying to check if all of the values in the dictionary exist in the list - `all(x in lst for x in dct.values())`

Answer (score 1):

You can try below approach

```
dct = { 'key1' : 'list1', 'key2' : 'list3'}
lst = ['list1', 'list2', 'list3', 'list4']
flag='N'
for each in dct:
   if dct[each] in lst:
      flag='Y'
   else:
      flag='N'
print (flag)
```

Comment: I don't understand why would anyone downvote it.. it's not that a bad approach.. lol..