# how to fix cannot read array in python 2

Tags: python

I want to take user data from `array["from"]`, but when i want to print it, it says `None`

This is for python 2.xx.  in the past i've tried with a basic array and it works fine, but when I use an Instagram bot and print in an app it doesn't work fine

```
print update.message
print update.message['from']
```

First code output :

```
> {'delete_chat_photo': False, 'new_chat_photo': [], 'from':
> {'first_name': u'error', 'is_bot': False, 'id': 0000000,
> 'language_code': u'kkk'}, 'text': u'namaewa?', 'caption_entities': [],
> 'entities': [], 'channel_chat_created': False, 'new_chat_members': [],
> 'supergroup_chat_created': False, 'chat': {'type': u'supergroup',
> 'id': -0, 'title': u'IE'}, 'photo': [], 'date': 1565793310,
> 'group_chat_created': False, 'message_id': 159}
```

Second code output :

```
> None
```

Comment: What about `print type(update.message)`?

Comment: For Instagram, if a message is returning `None`, it's most probable that there is no message in the user's inbox.

Comment: After your edit, I can see the message is a dict. I'm able to get the correct value from the dict for the key. But I'm using Python 3. You can try `message.get('from') `[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130768/return-none-if-dictionary-key-is-not-available). Also, why python2?? https://pythonclock.org/

Comment: 'Message' object has no attribute 'get' @Brennan

Comment: @CristiFati <class 'telegram.message.Message'>

Comment: @Cygnus as you can see the first output the text mean the msg

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `telegram.message` like a dictionary, but it's not. If you want the "from" portion, then you need to use `telegram.message.from_user` to get a return of type `telegram.User`

You can read about it in the [telegram docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.message.html#)