# Python: search dictionary using defaultdict from collections

Tags: python, python-3.x

please suggest below `loop` example using `defultdict in collections`,

i have referred this link for [defaultdict](https://www.accelebrate.com/blog/using-defaultdict-python)

My Question is how to write below loop example in `defaultdict in collections` to look for key `A` if not found key `B`, and return Null even if `B` is not found.

```
X = {'A': '1', 'B': '2', 'C': '3'}
Y = X['A'] if "A" in str(X) else X['B'] if "B" in str(X) else ("")
```

**first-priority:** if dict has 'A' it will return it's value - 1,
**second-priority:** if dict has 'B' it will return it's value - 2,
**third-priority:** if 'A', 'B' are not availble it will return blank - '',

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> ice_cream = defaultdict(lambda: 'Vanilla')
>>>
>>> ice_cream = defaultdict(lambda: 'Vanilla')
>>> ice_cream['Sarah'] = 'Chunky Monkey'
>>> ice_cream['Abdul'] = 'Butter Pecan'
>>> print ice_cream['Sarah']
Chunky Monkey
>>> print ice_cream['Joe']
Vanilla
>>>
```

required output:

if function is written in `defaultdict`.. i am expecting something like

```
function(a, b) --will search a, then b, if both are unavailable return "" (blank)
```

i want to avoid 'KeyError' and return blank/null if `a` and `b` parameters are unavailable in my dict.

please help..

thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return None if Dictionary key is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130768/return-none-if-dictionary-key-is-not-available)

Comment: Hi Sayse.. from above link i have found example to return 'Null'/any default value if parameter is not found.. But my requirement is to look for second possibility.. just like if function is written to do so.. function(a, b) --will search a, then b, if both are unavailable return "" (blank)

Comment: Hello! Is there will be only A, B or '' ? Or maybe there will be million of keys to get by priority?

Comment: Only A, then B,, else return Null

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid 'KeyError' and return blank/null if a and b parameters are unavailable, you can use the try except.

In this specific code, you can use:

```
a = {"A1": '1', "B": '2', "C": '3'}
try:
    result = a['A'] if "A" in str(a) else a['B'] if "B" in str(a) else ("")

except KeyError:
    result = ''
```

Let me know if it helps!
You can get more info here:

8.3. Handling Exceptions https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: thanks for your help.. i am looking if it's possible using collections module in python, instead of using dict.get('a', '') or try..except methods..