# Python: return a specific value while keys not defined

Tags: python

I have a dict `h`, the keys are int numbers:

```
from collections import defaultdict

h = defaultdict(dict)
h[1]=['chr1','12','20','1']
h[2]=['chr1','15','20','2']
print(h)
```

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {1: ['chr1', '12', '20', '1'], 2: ['chr1', '15', '20', '2']})
```

it works:

```
for i in range(1, 3):
    print(h[i][3])
```

```
1
2
```

but it's possible there are keys which were not defined and have no values, in which case, I want `h[i][3]` returns value `0`.
e.g. if I run:

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    print(h[i][3])
```

although I have used `from collections import defaultdict`, the result shows:

```
1
2
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-212d01eedb83> in <module>
      1 for i in range(1, 5):
----> 2     print(h[i][3])

KeyError: 3
```

**My question is, how could I make `h[i][3]` returns `0` when this `i` is not defined and then the result should be:**

```
1
2
0
0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Return None if Dictionary key is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130768/return-none-if-dictionary-key-is-not-available)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your values in the dictionary are lists.

So for `h[i]` `defaultdict` might help you if `i` doesn't exist but for the inner access, it can't help since there is no *defaultlist* which will return something if there is an empty list.

The best you can do is:

```
h = defaultdict(list)
h[1]=['chr1','12','20','1']
h[2]=['chr1','15','20','2']
for i in range(1, 5):
    print(h[i][3] if h.get(i) and len(h.get(i))>=4 else 0) # checks also that there is at least 4 elements in the list
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a try except.

```
try:
    for i in range(1, 5):
    print(h[i][3])
except KeyError as e:
    print('Key error - %s' % str(e))
    print(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `h.get(i,[0]*4)[3]`. Should do the trick. Although this assumes you won't index higher than 3. If you index higher you can return a longer array of zeros within the `get` method.