# How to use **kwargs to change a default value?

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I have a function (let's call it `foo`):

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    if kwargs.get("key") is not None:
        key = kwargs["key"]
    else:
        key = "default"
```

Here I have a default value for `key` but if `kwargs` has a value for `key`, I want to use that instead.

Is there a way to simplify this onto 1/2 lines?

Comment: `key = kwargs.get("key", "default")`? That's basically the whole _point_ of the `get` method.

Comment: Why is this even in kwargs? Why not just use the regular default argument mechanism? (You can make the argument keyword-only if you don't want it to be passed positionally.)

Comment: So I can just use `def foo(key="default")` instead? So what then is the point of `**kwargs` if I can just use that?

Comment: Because in some cases you might want to accept arbitrary keyword arguments, it just doesn't seem like this is really one of them.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by arbitary keyword arguments? Are you able to give an example?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1769403/3001761.

Comment: For example, `dict` lets you do `dict(x=3, justinbieber=4)` and get `{'x': 3, 'justinbieber': 4}` even though it doesn't have arguments named `x` or `justinbieber` declared. If you want to do stuff like that, then *that's* what `**kwargs` is for. It has nothing to do with default values.

Comment: Wrt _"So I can just use `def foo(key="default")` instead?"_ - **Yes**. `kwargs` exists to allow a function to have arbitrary keyword arguments, like in user2357112-supports-Monica's example. If you know which keyword args you want/expect for your function, those should be in the function definition. For the rest, use `kwargs` - see jonrsharpe's linked question above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return None if Dictionary key is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130768/return-none-if-dictionary-key-is-not-available)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use default value of `dict.get`

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    key = kwargs.get("key", "default")
```

Answer (score 0):

`kwargs` is essentialy of `dict` type. As such, the standard way (and the best-practise) of defaulting the value for a non-existent key is by using:

`kwargs.get(key, default_val)`