# Search a list elements in dictionaries

Tags: python

I want to take the elements of a list one by one and search them in 4 different dictionaries in python. then I want to create a new dictionary and put the elements of that list as keys and the values I found from those 4 dictionaries as values?

For example:

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
dict1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 2, 'c': 45}
dict2 = {'a': 15, 'b': 55}
dict3 = {'a': 79, 'b': 6, 'c': 3}
dict4 = {'d': 600, 'e': 30}
```

The result I want:

```
newlist = {'a': [10, 15, 79, 0], 
'b': [2, 55, 6, 0], 
'c': [45, 0, 3, 0], 
'd': [0, 0, 0, 600], 
'e': [0, 0, 0, 30]}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to write code to solve the problem?

Comment: That isn't "four different dictionaries", it's one dictionary which has 4 items. This is straightforward.

Comment: You simply want `dict1.get(key, 0)` to return a default 0 value if key not found.

Comment: do your 4 dictionaries share keys?

Comment: Now you've edited it to change one dictionary to four dictionaries. Please try to state the question correctly the first time, otherwise it invalidates answers people write you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This dict comprehension will result in what you're looking for:

```
dicts = dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4
{k: [d.get(k, 0) for d in dicts] for k in list1}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Return default value if Dictionary key is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6130800/202229).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```py
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
dict1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 2, 'c': 45}
dict2 = {'a':11, 'b':20, 'z':100}

def collect_values(list1, dictionaries):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for key in list1:
        for d in dictionaries:
            result[key].append(d.get(key, 0))
    return result

print(collect_values(list1, [dict1, dict2]))
```

Which would return

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [10, 11], 'b': [2, 20], 'c': [45, 0], 'd': [0, 0], 'e': [0, 0]})
```

EDIT

If appending zeros each time the key is not found in the dictionary is undesired behavior, the function below can be used:

```py
def collect_values(list1, dictionaries):
    result = defaultdict(list)
    for key in list1:
        for d in dictionaries:
            if key in d.keys():
                result[key].append(d[key])
            elif not result[key]:
                result[key].append(0)
    return result
```

Which returns

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'a': [10, 11], 'b': [2, 20], 'c': [45], 'd': [0], 'e': [0]})
```

Comment: I got this error : 'TypeError: first argument must be callable or None'

Comment: This sounds like it's coming from the instantiation of the defaultdict, have you definitively passed `list` as the argument?

Comment: In your question it looks like you overwrite the name `list` in your modules namespace, change `list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` to `list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`

Comment: I copied and pasted the first code you wrote. I didn't understand what the problem was. But now I tried it on a new notebook and the problem solved. Thank you :)